# How can I copy a transformation from one shape/layer to another, in PhotoPea?

Tags: transform, photopea

Say I've made two shapes as a new layer in PhotoPea.

I warp or use a perspective transform (or multiple!) on one shape. Is there a way to replay or copy that change onto a different shape/layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a shape layer or a bitmap layer to Smart Object. The shape stays there as a filled vector path.

Apply for ex. warping to the shape. If you double click the smart object in the Layers panel Photopea opens the original non-warped shape in a new window. You can edit he path or remove it and draw or paste a totally new one. In File menu you select Save Smart Object which updates the warped shape. Warping stays, but it's applied to the new content.

To copy existing warping to another shape but also to keep the original shape with its warping you duplicate the smart object and change the content of the duplicate. As said, you can remove the old path and paste another.

You must learn to use the path selection tool and the direct selection tool for path editing when the smart object is opened for edits. No edits are possible without opening the smart object in a separate window.

I admit it's complex, but it's worth the effort (tested). Have a good battle.

ADD: If it happens that you want to tweak an existing warping I unfortunately cannot tell any simple way to edit the warp mesh. But one can copy the original content out of the smart object and make a new one which gets different warping.

Comment: Does PhotoPea offer Smart Objects?

Comment: Yes. The program has been developed gradually to contain more and more useful functionality. There's even CMYK. I do not tried how well it works. Current version has vector tools in beta testing.

Comment: Cool. I was just curious. I've never used it.

Comment: That's a great answer. I was worried I'd have to learn smart objects, but it's comforting to know there's not an easier/less daunting alternative I've missed.